# Failed to execute shell script from "network" udev rule to change the MAC-address

Tags: networking, kernel, udev, mac-address

I am trying to execute a shell script from udev rule, when a network interface is added, as follows:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="eth*", PROGRAM="/usr/local/bin/changemac.sh", NAME="eth0"
```

The shell script is just changing the MAC address of eth1 using ifconfig command, as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:cc:dd:ee:ff:e1
echo "command return status $?" > /root/changemac.log
```

Above script is working fine from command prompt, but not executing from udev rule.
I also try to use RUN instead of PROGRAM in udev rule but no success:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="eth*", RUN="/usr/local/bin/changemac.sh", NAME="eth0"
```

Same script is executing from my custom module udev rule.

I think somebody must know this why it is not executing from network udev rule. :-)

Comment: `PROGRAM` is definitely wrong: this is executed before the device is activated, to determine how and whether it should be activated. I don't see anything wrong with the `RUN` rule. Does anything appear in the system logs? Did you run `udevadm trigger` to reapply the rule? What does `udevadm test net/eth0` show?

Comment: if it executed before the device is activated, then just add `sleep time` in your script then it will run later, have you tried this ?